# Subsetting over a vector with another vector

Tags: r, vector, subset, apply

Say I have a vector like

```
vector = c('hello','world')
```

and another two vectors like

```
vector2 = c(2,4)
vector3 = c(4,5)
```

How could I create a fourth vector that is the subset of each element in the first vector by the other two vectors? Something like

```
vector[1][vector2[1]:vector3[1]]
```

so for these vectors it would be

```
vector4 = ('ell','ld')
```

I've tried to use sapply but ran into a roadblock since I wasn't sure how I could write the function to subset them.

```
vector4 = sapply(vector, function(x) x[vector2:vector3])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered by `substr/substring`, which will iterate over each input:

```
substr(vector, vector2, vector3)
substring(vector, vector2, vector3)
#[1] "ell" "ld"
```

The two functions are slightly different. `substring` will extend to whichever input is longer and recycle:

```
substring(c("hello","nopes"), 1:3, 2:4)
#[1] "he" "op" "ll"
substr(c("hello","nopes"), 1:3, 2:4)
#[1] "he" "op"
```

This can be particularly useful when you want to extract multiple substrings from a single string:

```
substring("hello", 1:3, 2:4)
#[1] "he" "el" "ll"
substr("hello", 1:3, 2:4)
#[1] "he"
```

Comment: @d.b - `substr` and `substring` are 2 different functions.

Comment: better than `mapply`

Comment: Thanks, was a lot simpler than I thought it would be.